# Security through command line: is it a good idea? (PHP)

Tags: php, authentication, command-line, authorization

Is it OK to give full authorization to any request coming from the command line?

My idea was to make this check:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['argc']) AND $_SERVER['argc']>=2) {
    // it must be the admin, give him full authorization, no further checks needed.
} else {
    // normal web request, authentication needed.
}
```

Does this make sense?

Anything else I should know before I start using the command line to execute my php scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only safe if the server has only one user. Otherwise you need to either:

- Check for the correct user ID in the script
- Make the script only executable for that user

(This is assuming a Linux server)

Comment: yes it is linux, and I am the only user (for now). Okay thanks

Answer (score 1):

The command line is not a very good place from which to control your web application: your app displays HTML output, which is not much good to a human looking at a console (not to mention the JavaScript that won't work etc).

You could arrange for different output to be generated when running from the command line, but as a practical matter: why bother with all this? Why not have the administrator be authenticated from the web just like any other user?

If you want to have a special backdoor built into your app anyway though, I would suggest something like this (which is web-based):

```
define('ADMIN_BACKDOOR', true); // comment out to disable
$is_admin = defined('ADMIN_BACKDOOR') && $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1';
```

This is IMO next to impossible to exploit, and it allows you admin access from a natural environment (the browser).

Comment: I need this 'backdoor' because I want to be able to call scripts that are not accessible via web, and without the need of logging in to authenticate myself. I have little to no experience in administrating a server, and I am about to sign up for a dedicated server plan. I thought the command line was the best way for leting the cronjobs access my scripts. More specifically, I need to make a crawler start crawling from time to time. I have already built special output settings for when the command-line is used (eg: exceptions show up without any html)

Comment: Please explain "not accessible via web". If they are indeed not accessible, then what need is there for authentication? Also, I was under the impression that the scripts you want to call are part of your "main" application. If they are there specifically to be called by cron, then sure this approach is fine.

Comment: Not accessible via web means that they are outside the webroot, and they need to pass the check I wrote in my first post. Ok, so it's fine as long as they are ment to be called by a cron. Anyway I am still not sure how to handle these processes. How do I visualize what's going on with a script that has been called by a cron? Through file logs? And how do I stop it if I have to? (tell me if I need to start another topic for this)

Comment: To see what your cron processes do, redirect their output to a file (the simplest way would be to use a filename that includes date/time information, this way different runs will use different logfiles making it easier to track them down). As for stopping them, you can only kill the associated PHP process from the console unless you started it yourself (in which case CTRL+C will do). If this is not good enough for you, you need to put code in the scripts that periodically checks for a "stop condition" (e.g. presence of a file) and stops voluntarily when it becomes true.